# Какими должны быть общие второстепенные члены, чтобы...

Tags: пунктуация

...служить основанием для соединения частей сложного предложения только посредством интонации?

Давайте рассмотрим такое предложение: "Из пшеницы доверчиво поглядывали на нас васильки (,) и там-сям, будто капли крови, горели полевые маки". Это сложносочиненное предложение, и, как водится, между частями такого предложения знаки препинания не ставятся, если они объединены общим элементом. В данном случае в роли этого элемента может выступать второстепенный член "из пшеницы". Понятно, что и васильки, и маки растут среди пшеничных колосьев. Таким образом, обстоятельство "из пшеницы" относится и к тому, и к другому простому предложению, однако мы не можем включить его в состав второго предложения, не перестраивая последнего. Следует ли из этого, что запятая между частями сложного предложения в таких случаях необходима?

Предварительно благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятую не надо ставить в следующем предложении: "Из пшеницы доверчиво поглядывали на нас васильки и горели полевые маки".

Запятая не ставится, если общий второстепенный член  тесно связывает два предложения в единое целое, при этом мы имеем интонацию простого предложения, в котором обозначен перелом интонации, но отсутствует пауза.

Это преимущественно делается для нераспространенных предложений, что видно по примерам в Правилах 1956 года: "По улицам двигались грузовики и мчались легковые машины. От пристани каждое утро отходил катер или отплывала лодка".

Это правило не стоит применять механически - всегда можно сослаться на авторское решение.  И в любом случае запятую надо ставить, если одно из предложений имеет собственные знаки препинания, как в приведенном примере.

Comment: Предложения "По улицам двигались грузовики и мчались легковые машины" и "От пристани каждое утро отходил катер или отплывала лодка" можно без проблем разбить на два простых, в каждом из которых будет их общий второстепенный член: "По улицам двигались грузовики"; "По улицам мчались легковые машины"; "От пристани каждое утро отходил катер"; "От пристани каждое утро отплывала лодка".

Comment: А вот сказать "Из пшеницы горели полевые маки" мы не можем, мы можем сказать только "В пшенице горели..." Так вот меня интересует, влияет ли необходимость выбора другой падежной формы на пунктуацию.
В любом случае большое спасибо, Вы мне уже очень помогли.

Comment: Ну да, вы правы. Тогда тем более общего второстепенного члена просто нет. А то получится: поле - пшеничное поле - отдельные участки пшеничного поля, и все они влияют на выбор запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что обстоятельство "и там-сям" как бы нейтрализирует  предыдущее "из пшеницы", поэтому можно полагать, что общего второстепенного члена здесь нет, значит, запятая нужна

Comment: Ну вот и мне тоже так кажется.